# htaccess redirect or rewrite Rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Basically, I have this htaccess rule which I want to generalize:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)sale/details\.php\?id\=1234($|&)
RewriteRule ^properties$ /property/1234?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

I want to replace 1234 by a regex ([0-9]+) in the condition and retrieve in my rule as such:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)sale/details\.php\?id\=([0-9]+)($|&)
RewriteRule ^properties$ /property/$1?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

But it's not working, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is completely wrong. `% {QUERY_STRING}` means url QueryString  (the url part after `?` mark) .

Comment: Can ?you provide some examples of original and rewritten URLs